# Control Display Template

Tags: search-results, display-template

I created an Item display template and a result type for this template, I can see the Result type when I try to change the webpart properties for a search results webpart but.... for the Control, I can only see the Default control. I created my custom control but I cannot see it in the control dropdowns... actually i only see the default control.

What am I missing? How can I add my Control display template to that dropdown?

Comment: Where did you upload the Item control (It should be under Display Templates --> Search)? Is it checked in and published?

Comment: Yes, I uploaded those files there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Display templates--> Search. Edit properties of your Custom Control template and make sure in **Target Control Type (Search)** , Search Results is checked.